# CGContext Drawing two adjacent rhomboids produce a very thin gap, how to reduce it?

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext

The two adjacent rectangle is ok as image below.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    let leftTop = CGPoint(x:50,y:50)
    let rightTop = CGPoint(x:150,y:100)

    let leftMiddle = CGPoint(x:50,y:300)
    let rightMiddle = CGPoint(x:150,y:300)

    let leftDown = CGPoint(x:50,y:600)
    let rightDown = CGPoint(x:150,y:650)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.addLines(between: [leftTop,rightTop,rightMiddle,leftMiddle])
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    context?.fillPath()

    context?.addLines(between: [leftMiddle,rightMiddle,rightDown,leftDown])
    context?.fillPath()


    let leftTop1 = CGPoint(x:200,y:50)
    let rightTop1 = CGPoint(x:300,y:100)

    let leftMiddle1 = CGPoint(x:200,y:300)
    let rightMiddle1 = CGPoint(x:300,y:350)

    let leftDown1 = CGPoint(x:200,y:600)
    let rightDown1 = CGPoint(x:300,y:650)

    context?.addLines(between: [leftTop1,rightTop1,rightMiddle1,leftMiddle1])
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    context?.fillPath()

    context?.addLines(between: [leftMiddle1,rightMiddle1,rightDown1,leftDown1])
    context?.fillPath()
}
```

You may need to zoom in to see the gap. If I draw a thin line to cover the gap, then any width may overlap if the color has an alpha channel.

[image]

Change shapeColor to `let shapeColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)` and add `context?.setShouldAntialias(false)`
[image: let shapeColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)]

Comment: May I know why you want to draw those two as different paths? Why can’t you just combine those and draw as a single path?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan I actually want to draw a lot of rhomboids to composite a glyph in real time with different colors, but CGGradient or CGShading only accept linear gradient. Hence, drawing as a single polygon cannot provide gradient with multi colors align the center of the polygon. I have to draw a lot of it to show the color variation.

Comment: Do you have any pictorial representation of your desired result?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan I will show you when I am ready!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing it even with a rectangle. If you use the addRect it works, but if you add a rect with move and addLine, it shows a thin line on zooming as you saw.

Comment: @RPSM as Bonafons said, my problem (oblique line) is the problem of anti-aliasing, if you draw shapes with anti-aliasing enabled, it will automatically add lighter pixel to make it looks smoother. While you overlay these extra pixels with alpha channel added by drawing system, there will be more dense color come out. Ideally set one side of rectagle   to not enabling anti-aliasing should work, but it is a global setting now.

Comment: I am not sure if setting a proper blending mode may work.

Comment: Interesting. I'm having the problem in SwiftUI (but with CGPath) and unfortunately there is no way to turn off anti-aliasing on the layer in this manner. Darn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to screen resolution. On devices with high resolution one point actually has 2 or 3 pixels. That's why to draw an inclined line iOS draws some edge pixels with some opacity, when 2 lines are next to each other these edge pixels overlap. In your case I was able to fix the issue by making the following change

```
        let leftTop1 = CGPoint(x:200,y:50)
    let rightTop1 = CGPoint(x:300,y:100)

    let leftMiddle1 = CGPoint(x:200,y:300)
    let rightMiddle1 = CGPoint(x:300,y:350)

    let leftMiddle2 = CGPoint(x:200,y:300.333)
    let rightMiddle2 = CGPoint(x:300,y:350.333)

    let leftDown1 = CGPoint(x:200,y:600)
    let rightDown1 = CGPoint(x:300,y:650)

    context?.addLines(between: [leftTop1,rightTop1,rightMiddle1,leftMiddle1])
    UIColor.black.setFill()

    context?.fillPath()

    context?.addLines(between: [leftMiddle2,rightMiddle2,rightDown1,leftDown1])
    context?.fillPath()
```

Basically moving down the second rhomboid by 1 pixel (1/3 = 0.333...), I have tested on a screen with 1:3 pixel density, for the solution to work on all devices you'll need to check the scaleFactor of the screen.

Comment: And `context?.setShouldAntialias(false)` should set, though this option might affect the final result. But i think the pixel issue CoreGraphics does implicitly is exactly what I should care.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same result using the CGContext even if I use `setShouldAntialias(true)` or if I try to call strokePath() on the context. But it works fine with `sublayers`, `CGPath` and `strokeColor`

```
class RhombView: UIView {
    let shapeColor: UIColor = .black

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        let leftTop1 = CGPoint(x:200.0,y:50.0)
        let rightTop1 = CGPoint(x:300.0,y:100.0)

        let leftMiddle1 = CGPoint(x:200.0,y:300.0)
        let rightMiddle1 = CGPoint(x:300.0,y:350.0)

        let leftDown1 = CGPoint(x:200.0,y:600.0)
        let rightDown1 = CGPoint(x:300.0,y:650.0)

        var path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: leftTop1)
        path.addLine(to: rightTop1)
        path.addLine(to: rightMiddle1)
        path.addLine(to: leftMiddle1)
        path.close()

        let subLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        subLayer1.path = path.cgPath
        subLayer1.frame = self.layer.frame
        subLayer1.fillColor = shapeColor.cgColor
        subLayer1.strokeColor = shapeColor.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(subLayer1)

        path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: leftMiddle1)
        path.addLine(to: rightMiddle1)
        path.addLine(to: rightDown1)
        path.addLine(to: leftDown1)
        path.close()

        let subLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
        subLayer2.path = path.cgPath
        subLayer2.frame = self.layer.frame
        subLayer2.fillColor = shapeColor.cgColor
        subLayer2.strokeColor = shapeColor.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(subLayer2)

        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
}
```

If you remove both `subLayer.strokeColor` you will see the gap.

Comment: Sorry, if I add `context?.setShouldAntialias(false)` to my code, or add `alpha` to `shapeColor` of your code, it will cause overlap.

Comment: Your code actually added a default border `subLayer1.strokeColor = shapeColor.cgColor` to the shape, so it cannot show out, you can change another `strokeColor` or add some alpha to see it.